# no such table while inserting data in SQLDelight

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight, sqliteexception

All of a sudden my sample project is unable to insert data to table. it complains table not created. my sample GitHub(https://github.com/sreexamus/KMMSQLDelightPOC) removed the SQM file in the sample and tried. Not sure which plugin got updated on the fly which broke this.

Android SDK: 4.1 RC
SQLDelight: 1.4.3
KMM: 0.1.3 release
Kotlin: 1.4.10

Error:

Function doesn't have or inherit @Throws annotation and thus exception isn't propagated from Kotlin to Objective-C/Swift as NSError.
It is considered unexpected and unhandled instead. Program will be terminated.
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.Exception: android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException - no such table: Events (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Events(eventName, eventType, attributes, trackedAt)VALUES(?,?,?,?)

Comment: I would delete and install again. I'm not sure how you got it into that state, but the message is saying your db exists but table does not.

Comment: I did reset the simulator and ran it still the same issue.

Comment: Delete the app from the simulator.

Comment: @KevinGalligan deleted App, reset simulator. but still the same issue